# Hibernate Error Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I can't figure why I am getting this error and have been banging my head against a wall for a few hours now.

```
    session.beginTransaction();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<ActAsUser> actAsUser = (List<ActAsUser>) session.createCriteria(ActAsUser.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("actAsID.userID", proxyID))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("actAsID.targetID", targetID))
            .list();

    session.delete(actAsUser.get(0));
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

The code above gives me an error when trying to delete any row in the database that I have not added using Hibernate i.e. all the existing rows of the database that were entered through regular SQL.

```
Error: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

If I insert a row using Hibernate in my application I can then delete that row absolutely fine.

The thing I can't understand is that I get a user from the database first so I know that the user exists.

I've checked the Hibernate SQL and the only difference I can see is in the following when the select statement is run:

Working

```
/* criteria query */ select
    this_.PROXY_USER_ID as PROXY1_12_0_,
    this_.TARGET_USER_ID as TARGET2_12_0_,
    this_.EFFCT_DATE as EFFCT3_12_0_,
    this_.INCIDENT_NBR as INCIDENT4_12_0_,
    this_.TARGET_USER_NAME as TARGET5_12_0_,
    this_.EXPIRY_DATE as EXPIRY6_12_0_
```

Not Working

```
/* criteria query */ select
    this_.PROXY_USER_ID as PROXY1_16_0_,
    this_.TARGET_USER_ID as TARGET2_16_0_,
    this_.EFFCT_DATE as EFFCT3_16_0_,
    this_.INCIDENT_NBR as INCIDENT4_16_0_,
    this_.TARGET_USER_NAME as TARGET5_16_0_,
    this_.EXPIRY_DATE as EXPIRY6_16_0_
```

There is a difference in the numbers appended to the end of the columns, can anyone tell me what these actually mean and whether this could be the issue as this is the ONLY difference I can find between the two queries.

Comment: Are you use the row you want to delete is actually in the database before calling `delete`? When it says `actual row count: 0` means that it's not able to find that row to delete

Comment: 100% sure - the size of this list List<ActAsUser> actAsUser is always greater than 0 for all the tests I've done and I just ask Hibernate to delete the first user in the list.

My thinking is perhaps there is something wrong with the mapping as it is issuing a different select statement when trying to look for a user that has been entered into the database with SQL as opposed to in my application through Hibernate.

Comment: Have you looked in the database itself? Hibernate can cache it but not have it really saved. I would also recommend showing the Hibernate SQL with the bind variables in your Log4J settings (if you're not using it, I would recommend it) and see the exact SQL statement it's making.

Comment: You need to post your classes and configuration as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just worked it out

Hibernate Query for Delete statemenet not working:

```
Hibernate: 
/* delete com.package.ActAsUser */ delete 
    from
        CONFIG_ACTAS_PROXY 
    where
        PROXY_USER_ID=? 
        and TARGET_USER_ID=? 
        and EFFCT_DATE=?
13:39:01,460 TRACE BasicBinder:82 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - A534651
13:39:01,460 TRACE BasicBinder:82 - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - A512058
13:39:01,460 TRACE BasicBinder:82 - binding parameter [3] as [DATE] - 2014-11-03
```

PROXY_USER_ID     TARGET_USER_ID      EFFCT_DATE
A534651           A512058             2014-11-03 04:24:44

It's the time set on the date that does it.

When adding rows through hibernate the date looks like:

2014-11-03 00:00:00

Other rows in my database look like

2014-11-03 04:24:44

When I edit them and make the time 00:00:00 the delete then works.

Changing the hibernate mapping to map to a timestamp type instead of date fixes the problem in my application too.